# How to highlight textinputlayout on focus without bringing the keypad up

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-textinputlayout, android-keypad

I am trying to design a control of TextInputLayout, on click of which a pop up will appear to select item. I want to highlight this TextInputLayout when clicked that means showing floating label but don't want to show the keypad of edit text.

Please note: I am using TextInputLayout Edit text because i want the look of floating label when an item is selected.

Thank you

Comment: TextInputLayout layout = findViewById(R.id.til_my);
  layout.getEditText().setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);

Comment: @NehaRathore thanks for fast reply but it didn't work.

Comment: can you post your TextInputlayout here as it is working on mine

Comment: In my xml  android:inputType="none" , on TextInputEditText  also set try with both once

Comment: @NehaRathore superb! This is working. The one i just replied was for the previous comment which i guess u deleted. So i added input type to edit text of that TextInputLayout which didn't work. TextInputLayout layout = findViewById(R.id.til_my); layout.getEditText().setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL); worked for me.... Thank you :)

Comment: just upvote my repo if it worked for you

Comment: Update: So i added input type to edit text of that TextInputLayout in xml which didn't work. Adding programmatically worked.

Comment: i dont know why its is not working via xml both things are doing same, glad programatically worked for you